# How can I block bad sectors of HDD forever?

Tags: hard-drive, software

- How can I specifically determine and block bad sectors that is likely to fail in the future?
- Can anyone suggest a 3rd party freeware?
- I was using a freeware called Victoria. Does it help? And there are 4 options in the scanning but I am not clear how to get my job done permanently with this s/w. If this freeware works can anyone tell me how to use it and explain?

Answer (score 3):

If a hard disk starts to show bad sectors in its SMART data, the only responsible action in business environment is to replace the hard disk.

Comment: Isn't that a hard disk sector is to lose its efficiency with time. I am just looking a way to maintain it.

Comment: Yes, hard disk sector reliability decreases over time. When it shows as bad sectors, it is time to replace the hard drive. Trying anything else is not appropriate in business environment.

Comment: It is not showing bad sector yet. But they are slower. One red and some orange in the s/w that I checked with, that actually means that it is responding late. I wanted to block them. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Shuvo A latency scan can indeed show imminent failure, but you can't do anything about it. File systems allow bad sector marking, but it's meaningless, because the drive will transparently reallocate the sector when it sees fit. The OS has no idea anymore of _actual_ sectors, just _logical_ ones.

Comment: So without bad sector detected and problems like BSOD I don't need to worry?

Comment: Or still be a little concerned and replace a drive with bad performance and aging SMART attributes. Before it fails entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Put another way: Those signals of failure that *can* be responsibly dealt with pre-replacement *are* already dealt with by the firmware inside the drive; specifically designed and optimized for that disk design.

Over time that became the division of responsibilities, anything run on the CPU nowadays pretty much only needs a binary *good/no good* status, anything sector level is done on the drive.

Nothing you need to do, other than replacing entire drives.